# App Access Token can't retrive user public data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

In Graph API, if i make a request using a token generated by Graph API Explorer for the following query:

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/993673107328394

I get some results:

```
{
  "id": "993673107328394", 
  "first_name": "Johann", 
  "last_name": "Gomes", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/993673107328394/", 
  "name": "Johann Gomes", 
  "updated_time": "2015-01-19T16:00:34+0000"
}
```

But, when i use an App Access token, an exception is returned to me :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
    "type": "GraphMethodException", 
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

This is very strange because the only difference between user and app access tokens seems to be its valid time of use. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user#readperms

> - There are a number of fields called the public profile which are with `public_profile` permission.
> - Fields that aren't part of the public profile must be be requested with an access token with the relevant 'Extended Profile' permissions.

The first bullet point indicates that you *have* to use a user access token.